# What to call submit a new topic for a forum?

Tags: forum

What to call submit a new topic for a support forum with users that have little or no technical knowledge?

Looking online some of the ones that I have seen are:

- Ask Question
- New Thread
- Post a New Topic
- New Topic
- Submit a New Post
- New Post
- Create a New Topic

I like Ask Question but since we are not really a Q&A site and others can post new topics. What should you call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see why you wouldn't want to use "Ask a Question" since the user may not have a question. I'd be hesitant to use the terms "thread" and "post" since they are jargon words for online forums. While they are the correct words for this context, your non-technical users may not be familiar with them.

I would vote for

1. Create a New Topic
2. Start a New Topic